# How can I disabled the view change of react-calendar?

Tags: react-calendar

when I click the Prev Button or Next Button, there is not any function can control it. eg: When I click the Prev Button, I want a Toast a string, AND DO NOT GO TO THE PREV VIEW. However, there is no any Function can I disabled it.

I put the issue on the github of react-calendar, but the author says I should post this on here (stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prev/Next buttons are disabled based on `minDate` and `maxDate`. There's no way to manually disable these buttons.

You can use `onActiveStartDateChange` to monitor change of "active start date" (the date currently shown view starts on). `onActiveStartDateChange`, since 3.5.0, will also let you know using `action` which action triggered the callback.

Answer (score 0):

For the one using version less than 3.5.0, you can always use css to hide those buttons.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).